# AWS Amplify data not sync with dynamodb

Tags: flutter, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Amplify studio data is not sync with dynamodb. Everything was good until recently Amplify studio data occasionally doesn't match the item in the dynamodb.

Things I tried:

1. Generating 100 items from amplify studio
   Result: Items show up in dynamodb
2. Deleting items from Dynamodb
   Result: Items removed from Dynamodb but still exist in amplify studio
3. Deleting items using Flutter app with await Amplify.DataStore.delete(toDeleteItem);
   Result: Items removed from Dynamodb but still exist in amplify studio, but flutter app can't search this item anymore.

Is it a bug or something? Seems like my flutter app can retrieve the right data from dynamodb. Should I ignore this issue?